# Can't type AltGr characters in the OSX Terminal

Tags: terminal, osx, keyboard-layout

I probably messed up something and I can't type tilde and brackets in my terminal. I'm on Mac OS X but I thought this has something to do with Emacs that I use just from yesterday for an online course. What can I check?

Comment: Are you able to type those characters elsewhere, like in the Finder?

Comment: Oh yes! Tried even in editors like atom and sublime and I can type them

Comment: Do you get _other_ characters when you try typing tilde etc.? Does this affect only the command line in Terminal, or all applications (emacs etc.)?

Comment: No characters appear if I type them in terminal or emacs. In irb (interactive ruby) alt+è gives me ? instead of squared open bracket

Comment: Which keyboard layout do you use? I'm pretty sure this wouldn't arise on a US layout.

Comment: Italian layout keyboard

Answer (score 2):

You can use Emacs in the X11 environemnt. Then you can forget about the Meta-Key in default terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I solved unchecking the "use option as meta key" in my preference's terminal. But I fear it's not a solution because I need that for emacs.

Answer (score 0):

You should try [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com). It's generally better than Terminal.app. Sometimes you need to type `reset` to reset the terminal, it could be that too.